# ReduceRegions not returning values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, google-earth-engine-python-api, reduceregion

I am trying to reduce the percentage of crops from the CGLS-100 Landcover dataset for a set of points uploaded as asset from a shapefile. This is an operation that I've done tens of times, but for some reason in this particular instance `reduceRegions` doesn't return any value from the image - only the fields from the original shapefile. I need someone to check my sanity:

```py
# Load landcover
LC = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global")\
    .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31').first().select(['crops-coverfraction'])

# Load POIs
POI = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sebastienbiasse/barangays')

# Produce buffer around POIs
POI = POI.select(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3']).map(lambda feat: ee.Feature(feat).buffer(1000))

# Reduce
col = LC.reduceRegions(collection=POI, reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), scale=100)

# Remove geometry
col = col.map(lambda feat: feat.setGeometry())

# Request GEE to perform its magics
ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=col, description=f'LC_crops8', folder='CALDERA', fileFormat="CSV").start()
```

No error is returned, but the output csv file contains only the fields `system:index`, `NAME_1`, `NAME_2`, `NAME_3`, and `.geo`. I expect a field called `crops-coverfraction` as requested. Other SO answers to similar problems suggest that one source of error could be the size of the featureCollection and mine happens to be rather large (84k points). I get the same problem when using this instead:

```py
ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=col.limit(1000), description=f'LC_crops8', folder='CALDERA', fileFormat="CSV").start()
```

Can anyone spot an error?

The bizarre thing is that I reduce another image ~10 lines above this and it works perfectly.

Comment: You could try indicating the fields you wish to export in the selectors argument of the `Export.table.toDrive`.

Comment: I didn't know you could in `Export.table.toDrive`, I've tried specifying this in `image.reduceRegions` but to no change, and from my experience it natively exports all bands in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually work with Python so I worked out a solution directly on the GEE code editor. From what I can gather, there are two things that are messing up your code:

First, I think you might have to limit the number of properties to something ≤5000, though this might not be the case when exporting the results to the Drive.

Second, for reasons unbeknownst to myself, reduceRegions needs a crs projection (even though it's supposedly optional) to work in this case.

Here's the GEE code I wrote to test your python code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ee203842d4f9020ee718f1f6fb8451b7

Comment: Thanks Madeleine! As I mentioned, I also attempted to limit the number of exports without success. But I also reached the same conclusion yesterday: specifying `crs='EPSG:4326'` to `reduceRegions` solved the problem.